# how to get current logged windows username by php without windows authentication

Tags: php, single-sign-on

how to get current logged windows username by php without windows authentication?

I tried use javascript, but it need to enable one setting in the IE browser, it's not possible to ask all users to do that.

any other solutions?

my application is in DMZ, AD server in the intranet, there are in different domain..

Comment: If you tried to do it using javascript I'm guessing you won't have php script interpreted client side.
Then, I hope this is not possible, because that would seriously be some security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Current User:  `<?php echo getenv("username"); ?>`

List of the environment variables : `<?php global $_ENV; var_dump($_ENV); ?>`